# FFMPEG: How to keep only upper half of image?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to keep only upper half of the image in a video. How to do that? The original video is 2048x2048 pixels. I would like a 2048x1024 resolution video with the upper half of the original.
If I enter the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.avi -vf v360=fisheye:equirect:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180,transpose=1,crop=in_w:in_h/2:0:0 -c:a copy out.avi
```

then I get a 2048x2048 video where the upper half is black and the bottom is correct (it is the upper half of the original)...
The original video is from a 180 degree camera. If I omit the crop part from the video filter, then I get the desired perspective, but bottom half of the image is not needed...

Log:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'in.avi':   Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.48.100   Duration: 00:00:11.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3821 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 2048x2048, 3828 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 20 tbn, 40 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [swscaler @ 0000027b3e1d5a40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly Output #0, avi, to 'out.avi':   Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.49.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 2048x2048, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbn, 20 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.99.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s frame=  220 fps= 32 q=31.0 Lsize=    2368kB time=00:00:11.00 bitrate=1763.8kbits/s speed= 1.6x video:2353kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.634127%
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: OK, I have just extended my original post with all the details.

Comment: "in_h" crops the input, you want to crop the output, so use "h".

Answer (score 0):

OOops, I think I have found the reason: the v360 filter makes a 4096x2048 video from the 2048x2048 pixel original.